# What is the extension of a cookie?

Tags: cookies

This might sound like a simple question but I find it impossible to google it, because I get only results for various extensions to various programs that have something to do with cookies.

I came across this example code:

```
local ok, err = cookie:set({
    key = "Name", value = "Bob", path = "/",
    domain = "example.com", secure = true, httponly = true,
    expires = "Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT", max_age = 50,
    samesite = "Strict", extension = "a4334aebaec"
})
```

What does extension mean here?

Comment: could this example code be referencing some other library? because when looking here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set I'm noticing some inconsistencies in the properties of the object being passed (like `httponly` in the example, but according to mozilla the property should be `httpOnly`)

Comment: Seems like a WIP project. Here's all the information you need https://github.com/httpwg/http-extensions